# Induced electric field in a rotating cylinder without changing Magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism

The given question is from a problem, in which a metal cylinder was rotating about its axis of symmetry with an angular speed w. It is placed in a uniform magnetic field B. Now in the solution it states that an electric field must be generated which provides the necessary centripetal acceleration to an single electron. Now I was really not sure how to calculate this induced electric field as magnetic field is not changing. Could someone help me with this task.

Comment: Does the problem actually say that an electric field is produced? Or does it say that a force is created on the electrons? (I.e. the Lorentz force).